# How to successfully migrate or transfer a laravel codebase to a new laravel scaffold

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, git, vue.js

I want to ask if how do you successfully backup a laravel project / move it's codebase to a new laravel codebase, because my laravel project right now won't boot up the built in artisan server, it irks me so much, I wrote a lot of code in this project, and I want 2 make it work but I was really having a hard time with `git`, so I can't really find where's the bug in it that it won't serve, I checked out already on the part wherein I made the latest working commit, so I want to move the codebase to a new laravel app.

Comment: copy all the file & folder without vendor & paste.But it very much usefull to use git.

Comment: What's the error you get, what doesn't work?

Comment: it won't boot up the server, it's just skips.

Comment: It just suddenly skips then never run the server when I type `php artisan serve`

Comment: You can try removing the `vendor` directory and then `composer install` to install a fresh set of your dependencies, but if you've gone and screwed up something in the app itself, you're going to have to do some debugging.

Comment: You also need to figure out Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My "blind" suggestions are:

1) create a new laravel application and copy over all the functionalities one by one and see when it crashes
2) https://laravelshift.com/ (to also upgrade laravel itself if you want to do so)

Comment: Yeah, I jus thad this idea for like 30 mins ago. It just popped out of my head out of nowhere... you know how to fix 

> No write since last change when i say type `git commit --amend`

Comment: Looks like you're using **vim** for editing your commit messages. You need to leave the write mode by pressing `ESC` key and then `:x` or `:wq` to save and exit. I don't understand how this relates to your original question.